# UIDatePicker as inputView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I have two problems at `UIDatePicker` as inputView.

**1:** When I select "April 17 9 00 PM" in datePicker,
dateTextField outputs "2014-04-107 21:00:00".

**2:** UTC of My country is +0900.
But, `NSLog` outputs "2014-04-17 12:00:00 +0000".

How do I fix these problems?

```
@property IBOutlet UITextField* dateTextField;
@property IBOutlet UIDatePicker* datePicker;
@property UIToolbar* toolBar;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 600, 320, 216)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.datePicker];
    self.toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -40, 320, 40)];
    self.toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dateTextFieldShouldReturn)];
    NSArray* finishBarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneButton, nil];
    [self.toolBar setItems:finishBarItems animated:YES];

    self.dateTextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 293, 250, 30)];
    self.dateTextField.delegate = self;
    self.dateTextField.inputView = self.datePicker;
    self.dateTextField.inputAccessoryView = self.toolBar;
    [myScrollView addSubview:self.dateTextField];
}

- (void)dateTextFieldShouldReturn
{
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString* dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];
    [self.dateTextField setText:dateString];
    [self.dateTextField resignFirstResponder];

    NSDate* date = [formatter dateFromString:self.dateTextField.text];
    NSLog(@"%@", date);
}
```

Comment: `2014-04-17 12:00:00 +0000` is the same as `2014-04-107 21:00:00 +0900`.
Try logging out `[date descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/descriptionWithLocale:)) does that give a clearer result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this works for me:

```
- (void)dateTextFieldShouldReturn
{
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

    [formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"]];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];


    NSString* dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];
    [self.dateTextField setText:dateString];
    [self.dateTextField resignFirstResponder];

    NSDate* date = [formatter dateFromString:self.dateTextField.text];
    NSLog(@"%@", date);
}
```