# Automaticlly insert '/' in date field

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a uitextfield with format: DD/MM/YYYY, for example: 12/03/1982
I wanna when user type "2" and '3', this field will insert '/' after them automatically. I performed this in method:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

with check:

```
NSString *wholeTextName =
[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range
                                        withString:string];
LogDebug(@"WholeText: %@", wholeTextName);


    if ([textField isEqual:self.dateOfBirthTextField])
    {
        if (([wholeTextName length] == 2)||(([wholeTextName length] == 5))) {
        textField.text=[wholeTextName stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
        }
```

but when I'm typing to '2', result is on this textfield is:
'12/2' not '12/'=expected result
Could u suggest for me please?

Comment: A better option would be to change the input view for the text field into a date picker.

Comment: thanks @Fogmeister but in my case, require to use UITextfield

Comment: No, you misunderstand. Use a UITextField, with an inputView of a UIDatePicker. This will then use the datePicker to populate the UITextField instead of the keyboard. It also means that you get date validation done for free. For instance, what happens if the user type "29/02/2015"? Or what happens if they type "03/02/2015"? Is that the 3rd of February? Or is it the 2nd of March?

Comment: Check this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23132695/uidatepicker-as-inputview

Comment: thanks @Fogmeister, that's good ideas. I will try to use your way in my case

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to implement your desired result or textfield validation.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *wholeString = textField.text;
    if ((wholeString.length == 2 || wholeString.length == 5) && ![string isEqualToString:@""])
    {
       wholeString = [wholeString stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
       textField.text = wholeString;
    }
    else if(wholeString.length == 10 && ![string isEqualToString:@""])
    {
       return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Here i have added an else if condition to restrict more than 10 characters and one more condition `![string isEqualToString:@""]`, so even if you enter backspace, it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3 textfields for day, month and year instead of 1.eg-

[textfeild_day]`[label for "/"]`[textfeild_month]`[label for "/"]`[textfeild_year]